# method on activerecord::relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So i do have a User model, on which i need `by_posts` method. `by_post` is intended to be executed on already browsed users, eg on

```
users.where(name: "Jack")
```

I imagine this method as:

```
self.by_post(condition)
    return self if condition.blank?
    ##something
end
```

But right know when i return self like this, it returns a class, not a relation. So when i call this method on object such as:

```
    (byebug) users
    []
    (byebug) users.class
    ActiveRecord::Relation
```

what i get back after

```
users.by_post(nil)
```

is:

```
(byebug) users
User(id: integer, , username: string, email: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime etc
```

How can i make this method return the exact same object it begun with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i make this method return the exact same object it begun with?

`by_post` method operates on the class (`User`), not on the relation, thus what you get **is actually** the "object it begun with" :)

So in order to return a relation from the `by_post` method, you'd want to load it:

```
self.by_post(condition)
    return self.all if condition.blank? # self.scoped for Rails 3
    ##something
end
```

Comment: this works, you could add self.scoped as well, for rails 3

Answer (score 0):

If you use the self.methodname it will be added the the User as a class method.

```
User.by_post("jack")
```

If you want to call it on user instance skip the 'self.'

Like this

```
def by_post(condition)
    return self if condition.blank?
    ##something
end
```

Then you can use it like this

```
user = User.first
user.by_post("jack")
```

Comment: The second case looks like you are calling an instance method on a collection, which won't work.